# Swift: How to display multipe views and keeping all of them active

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I am building an App which has a map in the background and a draggable view infront of it, whenever a place is selected. Currently I am presenting my view with a custom PresentationViewController which makes sure that the animation is correct and the size and position are right. The issue is that I lose the ability to interact with the map behind the view that is being presented. I am trying to have it more like you can see in this gif here (which is a random app I found that has a similar structure and behaviour)

[image: App Demonstration Gif]

See the bottom part is draggable even while I interact with the map. How can I achieve that? Do I need child Views or do I need a specific presentation mode? I am new to swift and kind of lost to be honest.

Comment: for the behavior you want, I think you can use this: `https://github.com/scenee/FloatingPanel`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the view you are dragging from the bottom should not be in a separate ViewController if what you need is to still be able to interact with the viewController on the back. Try placing the view in the same viewController as your map view and that should solve the issue.